# Missing function in CEDET?

Tags: package, cedet, load-path

I get this error message when trying to configure CEDET:

> Symbol's function definition is void: ´cedet-gnu-global-version-check´

This is my elisp code:

```
(require 'auto-complete)    ; start auto-complete with emacs
(require 'auto-complete-config) ; do default config for auto-complete
(require 'yasnippet)        ; start yasnippet with emacs
(require 'cc-mode)
(require 'semantic)
(require 'semantic/ia)
(require 'semantic/bovine/gcc)

;; Enables global support for Semanticdb
(global-semanticdb-minor-mode 1)

;; Activates automatic parsing of source code in the idle time;
(global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode 1)

;; Activates highlighting of first line for current tag (function, class, etc.);
(global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode 1)

;; Activates displaying of possible name completions in the idle
;; time. Requires that global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode was enabled;
(global-semantic-idle-completions-mode 1)

(setq-mode-local c-mode semanticdb-find-default-throttle
             '(project unloaded system recursive))

(semantic-mode 1)

(when (cedet-gnu-global-version-check t)
  (semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode)
  (semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode))
```

*Did I forget something? How do I find the function in question?*

Comment: Yes. You did not load the library that defines function `cedet-gnu-global-version-check`.

Comment: Yes, I supposed this. But, how can I find what library provides it?

Comment: Search the CEDET source code (or other source code, if you don't find it there). If you have `grep`, use that (you can even use it inside Emacs: `M-x grep`). Otherwise, use whatever file-searching tool your platform offers.

Answer (score 1):

The `cedet-gnu-global-version-check` is defined within the cedet-global.el file, adding the `(require 'cedet-global)` statement solved my issue.

Comment: +1 for solving your own problem and posting the solution.  Hopefully it will help other people with a similar problem later on!