# Function: "Symbol's function definition is void" until I C-h C-f its definition, then works fine

Tags: debugging, require

I've defined a function that uses `popup-tip`. On startup, if I call the function, I get the error, `Symbol's function definition is void: popup-tip`. If I call `Ch Cf` for `popup-tip`, I can find the definition. Then, thereafter, the function works as expected.

I don't know what this could possibly mean.

Here's the function, if relevant. I've stolen it from here:
https://gist.github.com/jasonm23/eea3b4662e2a3028a07e

```
(defun describe-in-popup (fn)
  (let* ((thing (symbol-at-point))
         (description (save-window-excursion
                        (funcall fn thing) ;; This is the yield point
                        (switch-to-buffer "*Help*")
                        (buffer-string))))
    (popup-tip description
               :point (point)
               :around t
               :height 30
               :scroll-bar t
               :margin t)))
(defun describe-thing-in-popup ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((thing (symbol-at-point)))
    (cond
     ((fboundp thing) (describe-in-popup 'describe-function))
     ((boundp thing) (describe-in-popup 'describe-variable)))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-h C-h") 'describe-thing-in-popup)
```

Comment: Is it possible that `popup-tip` is from a library that does not ship with vanilla Emacs out of the box, and you have installed that package separately, and you have not loaded / required that package before trying to use one of its functions?  Methods of loading packages include, but may not necessarily limited to:  `load` and/or `require`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing function in CEDET?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29396/missing-function-in-cedet)

Comment: There are, I think, many duplicates of this question.